# Reverse fixed point conclusion

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

If I have a function such as:

$$f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$

where $M$ is any metric space denoted by :

$$(M,d)$$

$$f(x) =d(x,y)  $$ where $y \in M$ is a fixed point.

I am trying to show that this function satisfies the Lipschitz condition.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity
$$\frac{d(f(x),f(z))}{d(x,z)}\leq K$$ for $K \geq  0$

Currently I am stuck at two things.

First, the distance representation is not quite clear for me , I am not sure if I can use here  $d(x,y) = |x-y|$?

I only learnt two fixed points theorems, the Banach fixed point and the Brouwer fixed point.

Secondly, If I have a fixed point $y$ :
it could be a Banach case(unique fixed point), if $M$ is a complete metric space and If $f$ is a contraction i.e. $0 \leq K <1$

Otherwise, it is not unique fixed point.

I am not sure what approach should I use here? contradiction or  attempt some sort of reverse fixed point iteration direct proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle inequality implies that, for all $x_1,x_2\in M$,
$$
d(x_1,x_2)+d(x_2,y)\ge d(x_1,y) \quad\text{and}\quad
d(x_2,x_1)+d(x_1,y)\ge d(x_2,y)
$$
hence
$$
d(x_1,x_2)\ge d(x_1,y)-d(x_2,y) \quad\text{and}\quad
d(x_1,x_2)\ge d(x_2,y)-d(x_1,y)
$$
and therefore
$$
|\,f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=\big|\,d(x_1,y)-d(x_2,y)\big|\le d(x_1,x_2).
$$
So, $f$ is Lipschitz, with $K=1$.